# Include test-classes folder in the jar generated using maven plugin

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I have written some common code as a maven project as part of src/test/java package. I need to export this code as a JAR so that it can be reused as a dependency in other projects. When i create a jar manually using Export jar option in Eclipse, jar is created with target directory(and it's contents). This works fine when other projects use this jar as dependency

However, jar generated using maven plugin doesn't have target and other folders. I tried below options using the maven-jar-plugin but with no luck.

**Option1:**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-source-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.1</version>
                <configuration>
                **<archive>
                    <manifest>
                    <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                    <classpathPrefix>${project.basedir}/target/test-classes</classpathPrefix>
                    </manifest>
                  </archive>**
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>attach-sources</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

**Option2:**

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    **<outputDirectory>${project.basedir}/target/test-classes</outputDirectory>**
                </configuration>                                
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>test-jar</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

Below are the snap shot of jar generated.

**Eclipse option:**

[image]

**Maven test-jar plugin:**

[image]

Comment: Why do you think you need the content of the target directory and other folders? What you have in your *Maven test-jar plugin" is exactly what I would expect to see.

Comment: If you have common test code best is to make separate module put the code into `src/main/java`  and use it as usual dependency and limit it's scope by using `<scope>test</scope>` makes it easy to reuse also to test the common code within that common test module...

Comment: @Steve C These packages contain generic BDD step implementation and Reflections(0.9.10/11) is not able to scan these classes if jar doesn't have target folder.

Comment: @khmarbaise - I agree with you and we initially tried the same, but one of these classes need to always reference another class present in src/test/java. This fails the maven build as classes in src/main can't refer the one in src/test

Answer (score 1):

Classes in `src/test/java` are not meant to be reused in other jars. They are purely for running tests during the build (of that particular jar). If you need common classes for testing in different situations, construct a new jar with these desired classes (in `src/main/java`) and use it in your projects as a test dependency (`<scope>test</scope>`).